# Laravel 5 - withInput not working when used with redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

What I have been trying to do is to send a parameter as an input value and redirect with `Laravel 5.2`.

I have referred to the official documentaion, some postings on Stackoverflow and Laracast, and here are my attempts.

```
//This controller function is run by a POST method and gets an input value
public function makeCustomerId()
{
    return redirect('next')
        ->withInput();
}
```

Below is my next attempt, based on the documentation.

(The input value can be obtained by `$this->request->input('id', '')`)

```
public function makeCustomerId()
{
    return redirect()
         ->action('PageController@showNextPage', ['inputId' => $this->request->input('id', '')]);
}
```

I used the `dd()` function for debugging controllers, but nothing was sent for both cases.

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong?
Any advice will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

I add some more information.

The controller function above is run from the following `form`. This will eventually lead to `PageController@showNextPage`.

```
    <form action="{{url('makeCustomerId')}}" method="POST">
            <select name="id">
                @foreach ($teams as $team)
                <option value="{{$team->id}}">{{$team->id}}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

Maybe it's unclear, but the input parameter (`$this->request->input('id', '')`) corresponds to `$team->id`.

Below is how I use `$this->request`. In a nutshell, this is dependency injection, meaning that I use the `request` class from anywhere in the controller class by `$this->request`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PageController extends Controller {
protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the route to the PageController@showNextPage action? Does it include the route param 'inputId'?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added some more information, hoping this is what you mean.

Comment: And what exactly is `$this->request`? How you assign it and from which namespace it is?

Comment: Hi Marcin. That's dependency injection. I'll add more descriptions.

Comment: two thoughts: 1) are you sure you are able to load values for $team->id? and 2) what is your showNextPage method, does it accept the input and then pass it along to your next page view?

Comment: Hi tam.  1) Yes I am. Before I made the controller function `makeCustomerId()`, I used a different function, by which I could retrieve the `$team->id`.  2) `showNexpage` method is supposed to obtain the input value, use the value to access DB, get specific information from the DB and show it on a view.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, when you use `redirect` and `withInput`, the values will be available through `old('fieldName')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```
return redirect()
     ->action('PageController@showNextPage', ['inputId' => $this->request->input('id', '')]);
```

what you are essentially doing is making a new request with the `'inputId'` as input. So in your `showNextPage` method you would also need to access the `'inputId'` by saying something like this:

```
public function showNextPage()
{
    $id = $this->request->input('inputId');

    // do stuff
    // return next page
}
```